# Play multiple videos when dragged into an area with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am having a few issues with a script. For a project I have a container, this container has 8 separate thumbnails which when dragged into my container need to play the corresponding video. I have got 90% of the script working but having a few issues with the drag and drop side of things.

When a thumbnail is dragged into the location it is appending the video correctly but the thumbnail then freezes on top of the container... It should revert back, however when you drag another video in, it reverts back but the first stays fixed. Then when another is dragged into the container, this plays on top of my video. I need to tweak my script to simply:

1. Revert the thumbnail back to it's position.
2. Remove any current video that is there.
3. Append the new video.
4. Autoplay the video if possible.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: true,
        containment: "#content"
    });
    $(".drop").droppable(
    { 
          drop: function (event, ui) 
          {
             var url = $(ui.draggable).attr('videourl');
             var oggurl = $(ui.draggable).attr('oggurl');
             var $videocontainer = $('#video-container');
             var $video = $('#video');

             $videocontainer.empty().append('<video id="video" controls width="400" height="300"><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+oggurl+'" type="video/ogg" /></video>');
             $video.get(0).play();
          }
    });
});
```

My jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9tny5eh6/5/

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/karanmhatre/9tny5eh6/6/

**JS**

```
$(".drop").droppable(
    { 
          drop: function (event, ui) 
          {
              $(".drag").animate({
                  top: "0px",
                  left: "0px"
              });
             var url = $(ui.draggable).attr('videourl');
             var oggurl = $(ui.draggable).attr('oggurl');
             var $videocontainer = $('#video-container');

             $videocontainer.empty().append('<video id="video" controls width="400" height="300"><source src="'+url+'" type="video/mp4" /><source src="'+oggurl+'" type="video/ogg" /></video>');
             $('#video').get(0).play();
          }
    });
```

In the drop event, move all `.drag` elements to the original place using animate. Then, use `$('#video')` selector to select the video **AFTER** you have added it to the DOM.

The problem with your solution was that you were referencing the `#video` object from the DOM when it wasn't even present.

Revert the thumbnail back to it's position. - **Done**

Remove any current video that is there. - **Done**

Append the new video. - **Done**

Autoplay the video if possible. - **Done**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your scenario, You don't need to drop the element.You can just use drag function and check the coordinate positions.If the coordinate positions lie in the container then you play the video else not